# Does Intel MKL redefine functions from math.h in C?

Tags: c, performance, compilation, intel, math.h

I have an application written in C that uses `math.h`. I am wondering if I would benefit from linking with MKL at compile time, since I am not including `mkl.h` in my source code, and I intend not to use MKL directly in my source code.  I only want to include `math.h`, and use the basic API.

Would my application benefit from linking MKL at compile time? Does MKL redefine functions from `math.h`?

I intend to use OneAPI MKL 2021.1.0.